# webpack-dev-server: "script.js not found 404"

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
// public/index.html

<h1 id="headline">testing serving an index.html file</h1> // renders
<script src="testScript.js"></script>  // GET http://localhost:3000/public/testScript.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

testScript.js is also in the public folder so I'm not sure why dev server can find and render index.html but not its dependent script. Anyone know why that is? Here is my full 
 webpack.config.js

> Project is running at http://localhost:3000/ ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output
>   is served from / ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from
>   /home/owner/PhpstormProjects/app/buyUsed/public

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotEnvWebpack = require("dotenv-webpack");
const path = require("path");

const webpackConfiguration = {
  entry : {
    productFlow : "./frontEnd/productFlow/index.tsx"
    , adminArea : "./adminArea/index.tsx"
  }
  , output : {
    filename : "public/[name].output.js"
    , path : path.resolve(__dirname, "")
  }
  , watch : true
  // , watchOptions : { aggregateTimeout : 300 }
  , devtool : 'inline-source-map'
  , mode : "development"
  , devServer : {
    port: 3000
    , contentBase : [path.join(__dirname, 'public')]
    , hot : true
    , historyApiFallback : true
  }
  , plugins : [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new dotEnvWebpack
  ]
  , node : {
    fs: "empty" // needed for dotenv to work correctly
  }
  , resolve : { extensions : ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'] }
  , module : {
      rules : [
        {
        test : /\.ts(x?)$/
        , use : {
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
        }
        , exclude : [/node_modules/, /outputScripts/, /\.dependabot/, /\.next/, /\.idea/, /lib/, /pages/, /\.dependabot/]
      }, {
        enforce : 'pre'
          , test : /\.js$/
          , loader : 'source-map-loader'
        }
      ]
  }
};

module.exports = webpackConfiguration;
```

Comment: Instead using  `path.join` if it is in public folder then you should simply write like this `'./public'` in your `contentBase`

Comment: @Ronak07. Works now, thanks. Works on both `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/public`, do you know why?

Comment: Adding to the above comment, it looks like even bad URLS are auto-redirected to `/ ` whoch explains it

Comment: The output.js is your bundle.js file ?